# Detecting iBeacons UUID using Radius Networks Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I'm currently working on an app on Android which detects `iBeacons` using the API provided by `Kontakt`, to execute actions configured online in the `Kontakt CMS`.

However, to detect beacons, I am using the `Radius Networks BLE` libraries. I was unable to extract the UUID from the beacons, is this feature only available in the Pro Library? If it is available for the Open Source Library, how do I detect beacons with their UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Region region = new Region("myRangingUniqueId", uUID, null, null);
```

Should be able to range for that to get a list of beacons matching that uuid from didRangeBeaconsInRegion callback.

Unless you just want to range for all beacons, then you can leave the proxUuid field null (wildcard) and then iterate through and get the proxIds with
      iBeacons.iterator().next().getProximity()

Comment: @lundhjem : i am not able to detect multiple beacon. Is there any reason behind it. I kept uuid, minor major null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with the open source [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/).

First, make sure your beacons are transmitting properly by verifying you can detect therm with the free [iBeacon Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate).

If this works, take a look at the "Ranging Example Code" [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html), which shows how to read the beacon ids.

**EDIT:** This library has been replaced by one with a the [Android Beacon Library 2.0](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html).  The Ranging example is now available [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).

Comment: Hi, I am able to use this in the RangingActivity to display the UUID - iBeacons.iterator().next().getProximityUuid. But I am unable to implement this in the MonitoringActivity. Anything I'm missing out?

Comment: That is correct.  The monitoring API is designed to tell you only when you enter or exit a beacon `Region`.  It does not tell you the specific `Beacon`s that triggered the `Region` entry/exit.  For that you should use the ranging API.

Comment: "Ranging Example Code" link is broken.